# What is the distribution of this random variable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Find the distribution of this random variable:
$$X_t=\exp\left(t \int_0^t sdW_s\right)$$
knowing that $W$ is a Brownian motion in the filtered space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P,(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0} )$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any techniques from Ito calculus, let's write:

$$\int_0^t s dW_s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{kt}{n} \left  ( W_{\frac{(k+1)t}{n}}-W_{\frac{kt}{n}} \right )$$

Let $X_k = W_{\frac{(k+1)t}{n}}-W_{\frac{kt}{n}}$, then the $X_k$ are iid and $N(0,t/n)$. So we have

$$\int_0^t s dW_s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{kt}{n} X_k$$

Because $\frac{kt}{n} X_k$ are independent, we have

$$\text{Var} \left ( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{kt}{n} X_k \right ) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k^2 t^2}{n^2} \frac{t}{n}$$

This last sum converges to $\int_0^t x^2 dx = t^3/3$, so the integral is distributed as $N(0,t^3/3)$.

Incidentally, this shows that for any $f \in C([0,t])$, $\int_0^t f(s) dW_s$ is distributed as $N\left ( 0,\int_0^t f(s)^2 ds \right )$.

The remainder of the problem is to find the distribution of $\exp(X)$ when $X$ is $N(0,t^5/3)$. This is not a problem about stochastic processes, merely one about probability. Can you finish from here?

Comment: yes, it is enough! I think you intend $N(0, t^3/3)$ in the penultimate line instead of $N(0, t^5/3)$. thank you very much!

Comment: No, the $5$ was intentional. The additional factor of $t^2$ comes from the $t$ that was outside the integral in the problem statement.

Comment: Can you explain me why the series converges to the integral?

Comment: @Marco it is the definition of the stochastic integral? integrals are limits of sums...

Comment: @Marco $\int_0^t f(s) dW_s$ is defined to be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(kt/n) \left ( W_{(k+1)t/n} - W_{kt/n} \right )$, as I wrote above. If you meant why the last sum converges to the integral, this is just the definition of a Riemann sum from calculus.